# xml generation performance issue

Tags: java, xml, performance, jdom

I have  to create xml response with speed performance. 
E.g want to generate hotel search response xml. 
Hotel bean contain multiple room bean data with details.

If have observed that currently jdom V1. 0 taking more than 2.5 second to generate xml of 2500 object.

Currently i am using jdom version 1.0 for xml generation.

I have to make it faster. Kindly suggest.

**CODE SAMPLE**

```
public Document getSearchResponseXmlDoc(ArrayList alHotelList,HotelSearchParams searchParams){
    Document xmlDocument = new Document();
    Element rootElement;

    if (this.isHotelRooms) {
        rootElement = new Element(HotelXmlTags.HOTEL_ROOMS_RESPONSE);
        xmlDocument.addContent(rootElement);
    } else {
        rootElement = new Element(HotelXmlTags.HOTEL_SEARCH_RESPONSE);
        xmlDocument.addContent(rootElement);
    }

    Element elClientinfo=generateClientInfo(searchParams);
    rootElement.addContent(elClientinfo);

    Element hotelSearchRequestElement;

    if (this.isHotelRooms) {
        hotelSearchRequestElement = new Element(HotelXmlTags.HOTEL_ROOMS_REQUEST);
        rootElement.addContent(hotelSearchRequestElement);
    } else {
        hotelSearchRequestElement = new Element(HotelXmlTags.HOTEL_SEARCH_REQUEST);
        rootElement.addContent(hotelSearchRequestElement);
    }

    Element hotelInfoElement = new Element(HotelXmlTags.HOTEL_SEARCH_HOTEL_INFO);
    hotelSearchRequestElement.addContent(hotelInfoElement);

    //TODO: Commnenting searchparms sending, should be uncommented if needed

    Element countryElement = new Element(HotelXmlTags.HOTEL_SEARCH_COUNTRY);
    countryElement.setText(searchParams.getCountry());
    hotelInfoElement.addContent(countryElement);

    Element countryCodeElement = new Element(HotelXmlTags.HOTEL_SEARCH_COUNTRY_CODE);
    countryCodeElement.setText(searchParams.getCountryCode());
    hotelInfoElement.addContent(countryCodeElement);

    Element roomingSearchParams = new Element(HotelXmlTags.HOTEL_SEARCH_ROOMING_INFO);
    final ArrayList<RoomingSearchParams> roomSearchParamList = searchParams.getRoomingList();
    int roomno=1;
    for (final RoomingSearchParams roomSearchParam : roomSearchParamList)
    {
        Element room = new Element(HotelXmlTags.HOTEL_SEARCH_ROOM_INFO);

        Element elRoomno = new Element(HotelXmlTags.HOTEL_SEARCH_ROOM_NUMBER);
        elRoomno.addContent(Integer.toString(roomno));
        room.addContent(elRoomno);

        Element roomcode = new Element(HotelXmlTags.HOTEL_SEARCH_ROOM_CODE);
        roomcode.addContent(roomSearchParam.getRoomTypeDisplay());
        room.addContent(roomcode);

        Element adultno = new Element(HotelXmlTags.HOTEL_SEARCH_NUMBER_OF_ADULTS);
        adultno.addContent(Integer.toString(roomSearchParam.getNoOfAdultInRoom()));
        room.addContent(adultno);
        Element childno = new Element(HotelXmlTags.HOTEL_SEARCH_NUMBER_OF_CHILDREN);
        childno.addContent(Integer.toString(roomSearchParam.getNoOfChildInRoom()));
        room.addContent(childno);

        Element child = new Element(HotelXmlTags.HOTEL_SEARCH_CHILD);
        ArrayList<String> alChildAges = roomSearchParam.getArrChildAgeArray();
        for (final String sChildAge : alChildAges)
        {
            Element age = new Element(HotelXmlTags.HOTEL_SEARCH_AGE);
            age.addContent(sChildAge);
            child.addContent(age);
        }
        room.addContent(child);

        Element ExtraBedRequested = new Element(HotelXmlTags.HOTEL_SEARCH_CHILD_EXTRA_BED);
        ExtraBedRequested.addContent(roomSearchParam.IsExtraBedRequested()?"Y":"N");
        room.addContent(ExtraBedRequested);


        roomingSearchParams.addContent(room);
        roomno++;
    }

    hotelInfoElement.addContent(roomingSearchParams);

    Element hotelSearchDetailsElement = formSearchResponseXml(alHotelList, searchParams);
    rootElement.addContent(hotelSearchDetailsElement);

    return xmlDocument;
}
```

**XML response sample :**

```
<HotelRoomsResponse>
<clientinfo>
    <clientid>58263</clientid>
    <searchId>97081714-2c09-41dd-9282-2457a516837a</searchId>
</clientinfo>
<HotelSearchRequest>
    <hotelinfo>
        <country>United Arab Emirates</country>
        <city>Dubai</city>
        <checkindate>20/09/2019</checkindate>
        <noOfNight>2</noOfNight>
        <checkoutdate>22/09/2019</checkoutdate>
        <nationality>United Arab Emirates,AE</nationality>
        <norooms>2</norooms>
        <starrating>0</starrating>
        <roomtype></roomtype>
        <Language>en</Language>
    </hotelinfo>
</HotelSearchRequest>
<IsFinalResult>true</IsFinalResult>
<IsPreCombinedRoomRes>false</IsPreCombinedRoomRes>
<HotelSearchDetails>
    <hoteldetail>
        <hotelTrackId>97081714-2c09-41dd-9282-2457a516837a00000GTAHTR00000005</hotelTrackId>
        <hotelname>MIDDLE EAST HOTEL</hotelname>
        <hoteldesc />
        <checkintime />
        <checkouttime />
        <hotelchain></hotelchain>
        <pricing_model>R</pricing_model>
        <starrating>3.0</starrating>
        <phone>42226688</phone>
        <address>AL MUSALLA ROAD&lt;br&gt;OPP. NAIF PARK&lt;br&gt;Dubai City DEIRA 1590&lt;br&gt;United Arab Emirates&lt;br&gt;http://www.middleeas.com/</address>
        <CityLocation></CityLocation>
        <city>Dubai</city>
        <country>United Arab Emirates</country>
        <longitude>55.306227000000000</longitude>
        <latitude>25.273999000000000</latitude>
        <RepriceSupported>true</RepriceSupported>
        <image>http://images.gta-travel.com/HH/Images/EM/DXB/DXB-MID4-9.jpg</image>
        <isPostSearchRomingApplicable>N</isPostSearchRomingApplicable>
        <hotelamenities />
        <HotelPolicyIndicator isRefundable="true" isNonRefundable="false" />
        <roomdetail roomIndex="1" contractType="GT-DXB-MID4">
            <PrimarySupplierName>GTA</PrimarySupplierName>
            <ExternalSupplierName>GTA</ExternalSupplierName>
            <PrimaryHotelName>MIDDLE EAST HOTEL</PrimaryHotelName>
            <PrimaryHotelAddress>AL MUSALLA ROAD&lt;br&gt;OPP. NAIF PARK&lt;br&gt;Dubai City DEIRA 1590&lt;br&gt;United Arab Emirates&lt;br&gt;http://www.middleeasthoteldubai.com/</PrimaryHotelAddress>
            <supplierCurrency>EUR</supplierCurrency>
            <roomCombId>97081714-2c09-41dd-9282-2457a516837a00000GTAHTR00000005RCMB00000000</roomCombId>
            <AllocationStatus>A</AllocationStatus>
            <RoomPolicyIndicator isNonRefundable="false" />
            <luxurytax>0.0</luxurytax>
            <servicetax>0.0</servicetax>
            <buyingAmount>87.76</buyingAmount>
            <totalmarkup>36.83980504000001</totalmarkup>
            <totalgeneraltax>0.0</totalgeneraltax>
            <totalservicetax>0.0</totalservicetax>
            <totaldiscount>40.523785544</totaldiscount>
            <totaladmintransfee>36.83980504000001</totaladmintransfee>
            <totalagenttransfee>0.0</totalagenttransfee>
            <suppToClientExchangeRate>4.19779</suppToClientExchangeRate>
            <agentSellingAmount>401.553874936</agentSellingAmount>
            <adminSellingAmount>401.553874936</adminSellingAmount>
            <outputTaxes userType="ADM" />
            <totalservicetax>0.0</totalservicetax>
            <currency>AED</currency>
            <supplierId>5544</supplierId>
            <supplierName>GTA</supplierName>
            <isCommissionableRate>N</isCommissionableRate>
            <commissionPerc>0.0</commissionPerc>
            <priceWithoutOffer>0.0</priceWithoutOffer>
            <totalPrice>401.553874936</totalPrice>
            <isPackage></isPackage>
            <isExtraInfoRequiredForBooking>N</isExtraInfoRequiredForBooking>
            <isGTASharingBedding>Y</isGTASharingBedding>
            <isQuoteBooking>false</isQuoteBooking>
            <isFareChange>false</isFareChange>
            <roomingPriceDetail>
                <roominfo>
                    <roombasis> Room and Breakfast Continental</roombasis>
                    <roomtype>DOUBLE STANDARD</roomtype>
                    <RoomDesc>DOUBLE STANDARD</RoomDesc>
                    <roomno>1</roomno>
                    <roomcode>SGL_1</roomcode>
                    <pricepernight>200.776937468</pricepernight>
                    <totaltaxamount>0.0</totaltaxamount>
                    <rateRemark></rateRemark>
                    <pricebreakup>
                        <slab>
                            <rateslab>1</rateslab>
                            <fromdate>20/09/2019</fromdate>
                            <todate>21/09/2019</todate>
                            <amount>200.776937468</amount>
                            <roomStatus>AVAILABLE</roomStatus>
                        </slab>
                        <slab>
                            <rateslab>2</rateslab>
                            <fromdate>21/09/2019</fromdate>
                            <todate>22/09/2019</todate>
                            <amount>200.776937468</amount>
                            <roomStatus>AVAILABLE</roomStatus>
                        </slab>
                    </pricebreakup>
                </roominfo>
            </roomingPriceDetail>
            <roomingAmenities />
            <roomRateDesc></roomRateDesc>
            <roomRateNotes />
            <supplementDetails />
        </roomdetail>
        <IsPriceChanged>false</IsPriceChanged>
        <Offer></Offer>
        <Remark />
    </hoteldetail>
</HotelSearchDetails>
```

Comment: Can you show your current code for the generation?

Comment: How much data are you generating in that 2.5 seconds? How are you obtaining the data? Please could you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem?

Comment: You can use jaxb for converting bean to xml and vice versa

Comment: With performance the devil is always in the detail. The fact that you are using JDOM 1.0 is only one of hundreds of things we need to know to find the performance issue, and the chances are that it's not relevant. You are doing something wrong, and unless you tell us more about what you are doing, we can't tell you what it is.

Comment: You can try distributed approach where 2500 items will be divided in 4 parts and concurrently 4 threads will work on these 4 parts to generate XML and then generated elements will be merged. Once it is merged you can return it as XML string.